# ARC Semantic Issue : No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am new to flutter. I am trying to create IOS build using VS Code and getting below 2 errors:

1. ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector
   'imageByPreparingForDisplay'
2. ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector
   'imageByPreparingThumbnailOfSize:'

Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: @matt do u have any solution on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this arun?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is presented in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923430/flutter-xcode-build-failure-no-visible-interface-for-uiimage-declares-the-se).

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  pod 'SDWebImage', '5.12.6'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

May be if you are using file_picker or any other flutter dependencies related to UIImage then you can update those to latest version