# Flutter Xcode Build Failure: no visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'imageByPreparingForDisplay'

Tags: ios, flutter, uiimage, sdwebimage

`ARC Semantic Issue: no visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'imageByPreparingForDisplay'`

So I have been going through the difficult task of getting my client's Flutter app over to IOS and built.
I have been documenting a long thread here: [What is a podfile target, and how to I specify Flutter modules for IOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915218/what-is-a-podfile-target-and-how-to-i-specify-flutter-modules-for-ios-version) after I was having a ton of difficulty getting all of my packages imported and the pods working.

Well I got those imported, and any pod warning fixed, but now the fatal error is coming from a pod package itself. This snippet is taken right from the error log:

```
/Users/prime/Desktop/ticket_board-master/ticket_board-master/ios/Pods/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/Core/SDImageCoderHelper.m:31:40: error: no visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'imageByPreparingForDisplay'
        UIImage *decodedImage = [image imageByPreparingForDisplay];
```

Note that this app builds for Android, so I don't think its an issue with my existing code, but rather the package itself? Maybe I need to change something between IOS and Android?
I tried just googling the error and searching here with no luck.
I found another thread here: [Can't build on iOS - SDWebImage: ARC Semantic Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364951/cant-build-on-ios-sdwebimage-arc-semantic-issue)
That seems to be the same issue as mine, and nobody has answered it, aside from the last ditch effort of completely deleting and recreating the entire IOS folder. Which I tried and doesn't work for me.

I also saw this thread here, which suggested going down a version, but also didn't work: https://bytemeta.vip/repo/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/1064

I've actually seen several threads on this that go left unanswered.
I'll keep this updated if I find anything, but its not looking good.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works here: https://bytemeta.vip/repo/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/1064

However it is just a temporary fix until the newest version is properly fixed.

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  pod 'SDWebImage', '5.12.6'
end
```

This HAS to go in the podfile. You can't change the pod package version anywhere else. It won't work. You then have to run `pod update` in your ios sub directory to install the older version.